# Keeping user logged in with jsp

Tags: java, html, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to keep a user logged in after the login page; I'm on Apache Tomcat using jsp page (NO servlet, It is a university project), NO DB.

My problem is, after login page, the user have right username and password (I verify this with **`<%System.out.println( usernameUser + " " + passwordUser ); %>`** in the new page).
In this new page I have a new form where user can submit other information (obv different from his username and password); this submit is on this page itself, but after this username and password became "null".

Here the code

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<jsp:useBean id="proprietarioBean" scope="session" class="gestioneLocazioni.ProprietarioBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="proprietarioBean" property="*" /> 

<%System.out.println( request.getParameter("username") + " " + request.getParameter("password") ); %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    [OTHER CODE]

    <form action="ProprietarioLogin.jsp" name="myform" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome locazione:</td>
            <td><input name="nomeLoc" id="nomeLoc" type="text"></td>                 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome proprietario della locazione:</td>
            <td><input name="nomeProp" id="nomeProp" type="text"></td>              
        </tr>

        <tr>    
            <td><input name="aggLoc" id="aggLoc" type="submit" value="Aggiunti locazione"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <%if( request.getParameter("aggLoc") != null){ 
                String nomeLoc = request.getParameter("nomeLoc");
                String nomeProp = request.getParameter("nomeProp");

                if(proprietarioBean.validateInsert(nomeLoc, nomeProp)){ 
                    System.out.println("Locazione inserita: " + request.getParameter("nomeLoc")); 
                    proprietarioBean.richiediInserimento(request.getParameter("nomeLoc"), request.getParameter("nomeProp"));>
                    <p><b>Locazione inserita:</b> <%=request.getParameter("nomeLoc")%> </p>
                    <%  int k = proprietarioBean.dimList(); 
                    System.out.println("k vale: "+ k);
                    for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++){
                        %><p> <%=proprietarioBean.getLocazionePend(i) %></p><%
                    }
                  }

              else{
                System.out.println("Dati errati"); %>
                   <p><strong>DATI ERRATI</strong></p><%  
                   }
            }%>
               </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    </form>
```

If need I can append login's code.
Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT
Now I can get right username and password like this:

```
String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");           
String password = (String) session.getAttribute("password");
System.out.println( "Da session.getAttribute: " + username + " " + password +"\n");
```

Now I must use this information for the jsp:setProperty ?

**EDIT 2: Solved!**

thanks to all for answer.
I solved with this:

```
proprietarioBean.setUsername((String) session.getAttribute("username"));
proprietarioBean.setPassword((String) session.getAttribute("password"));
```

Comment: not exactly a good practice but fine for a school project . http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm ... save something in **session** . every hit to jsp page check for session object

Comment: Yes, use request.getSession().setAttribute("loginName", loginName) or similar.

Comment: Thanks.
The problem is that there he take userId from "new String("blabla");" not from "request.getParameter(..)".
I can try that but I'm not sure how to fit it for my code, can you suggest me somethings?

Comment: user types bigghe & password , then you store in session key:user value:bigghe .... when jsp page loades , get from session key:user . and IF object is null , no login and show login page else you have login and do not show login page . Note after this works you are supposed to give it improvements , this is just a rough idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll basically have something like this

Login.jsp( the page that processes log in)

```
<%
//save just user name in session
request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", request.getParameter  ("username"));
 %>
```

On some other page, you'll check that userName is not null

```
<%
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("userName") != null)
 //do something
else 
//do something else
%>
```

You can invalidate the session by

```
<% request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", null);%> //or
//just call the invalidate method on the session object
```

Comment: Ok, it seems like what I've done:
"session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));"

but probably I must use your code right?
After this, have I to use "jsp:setProperty blabla" with this param?

Comment: Yes, just add that field to your proprietarioBean class and check that userName is not null. Or alternatively, check that the session variable is not null inside your jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is store the user and the password encrypted in a cookie.

For example:

```
if(rememberMe){

Cookie c = new Cookie("userid", userId.toString());
c.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
response.addCookie(c);  // to add it to the response
```

}

And then to read the cookie you can do something like this:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();     

boolean foundCookie = false;

for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{ 
    Cookie c = cookies[i];
    if (c.getName().equals("userid")){
        string userId= c.getValue();
        foundCookie = true;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) you can find the official documentation and more information about cookies